# SilverStripe 3.6.1 - Use renderWith to display a loop of data objects

Tags: php, silverstripe

I'm working on rendering an array of data objects to a template using renderWith() but having some difficulty. What I have now does not render anything in the specified template except for whatever is in the basic Content WYSIWYG editor.

As a side note, I'm using the shortcodable module for reference, hence why the code is setup the way it is.

This is the function I have setup in a data object called Drawer which is meant to display a list of `DrawerContents` into the `FaqLisitng` template:

```
public function parse_shortcode($attributes, $content, $parser, $shortcode) 
{
        $drawers = "";
        if (isset($attributes['Drawers'])) {
            $Idx = explode(',', $attributes['Drawers']);
            $drawerIdx = [];
            foreach ($Idx as $did) {
                $d = Drawer::get()
                    ->filter('ID', $did)
                    ->first();
                if ($d->ID) {
                    array_push($drawerIdx, $d->ID);
                }
            }
            $drawers = implode(',', $drawerIdx);
        }
        $drawerContents = DrawerContent::get()->filter(
            array("DrawerID" => $drawers));

        $drawerContentArray = array();
        foreach($drawerContents as $dca){
            $drawerContentArray = new ArrayData(array(
                'FaqQuestion' => $dca->FaqQuestion,
                'FaqAnswer' => $dca->FaqAnswer
            ));
        }
        return $drawerContentArray->renderWith('FaqListing');
    }
```

And this is the `FaqListing` template contents:

```
<% with $getFaqListing %>
    <strong>$FaqQuestion</strong><br/>
    $FaqAnswer
<% end_with %>
```

I noticed that if I remove the `with` block, I do get the last entry for each DrawerContent data object that is being called in the `parse_shorcode` function, only the first entry--not the entire list for each DrawerContent data object. I get the same results if I use a loop instead of with.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I feel like I'm close to getting things setup correctly.

For reference, in case it may help in providing a solution, here is the entire code for the `Drawer` data object:

```
<?php

class Drawer extends DataObject {

    private static $db = array(
        'FaqCategoryName' => 'varchar(250)',
    );

    private static $summary_fields = array(
        'FaqCategoryName'       => 'FAQ Category Name',
    );
    private static $has_many = array(
        'DrawerContents' => 'DrawerContent',
    );
    /**
     * Parse the shortcode and render as a string, probably with a template
    Add a comment to this line
     * @param array $attributes the list of attributes of the shortcode
     * @param string $content the shortcode content
     * @param ShortcodeParser $parser the ShortcodeParser instance
     * @param string $shortcode the raw shortcode being parsed
     * @return String
     **/
    public function parse_shortcode($attributes, $content, $parser, $shortcode) {
        $drawers = "";
        if (isset($attributes['Drawers'])) {
            $Idx = explode(',', $attributes['Drawers']);
            $drawerIdx = [];
            foreach ($Idx as $did) {
                $d = Drawer::get()
                    ->filter('ID', $did)
                    ->first();
                if ($d->ID) {
                    array_push($drawerIdx, $d->ID);
                }
            }
            $drawers = implode(',', $drawerIdx);
        }
        $drawerContents = DrawerContent::get()->filter(
            array("DrawerID" => $drawers));

        $drawerContentArray = array();
        foreach($drawerContents as $dca){
            $drawerContentArray = new ArrayData(array(
                'FaqQuestion' => $dca->FaqQuestion,
                'FaqAnswer' => $dca->FaqAnswer
            ));
        }
        return $drawerContentArray->renderWith('FaqListing');
    }

    public function getShortcodableRecords() {
        return Drawer::get()
            ->map('ID')
            ->toArray();
    }

    /**
     * Returns a list of fields for editing the shortcode's attributes
     * in the insert shortcode popup window
     *
     * @return Fieldlist
     **/
    public function getShortcodeFields()
    {
        $all = Drawer::get()->map('ID');

        $DrawersMultiList = ListboxField::create("Drawers", "Drawers")
            ->setMultiple(true)
            ->setSource($all);

        return FieldList::create([
            $DrawersMultiList,
        ]);


    }
    public function canView($member = null){
        return true;
    }

    public function canEdit($member = null) {
        return true;
    }

    public function canCreate($member = null) {
        return true;
    }

    public function getTitle(){
        $title = $this->FaqCategoryName;

        return $title;
    }

}

class DrawerAdmin extends ModelAdmin {
    private static $managed_models = array('Drawer');
    private static $url_segment = 'Drawers';
    private static $menu_title = 'Drawers';
}
```

And code for the `DrawerContent` data object:

```
<?php

class DrawerContent extends DataObject {

    private static $db = array(
        'FaqQuestion' => 'varchar',
        'FaqAnswer' => 'HTMLText',
    );
    private static $has_one = array(
        'Drawer' => 'Drawer',
    );
    private static $summary_fields = array(
        'FaqQuestion'       => 'FAQ Question',
    );

}
```

And the $getFaqListing function, which is created in `Page.php`

```
public function getFaqListing() {
    return DrawerContent::get();
}
```

Comment: I would look at using `ArrayList` instead of using an array to store the ArrayData elements. `$drawerContentArray = ArrayList::create();`

Comment: Made that change but it didn't make any difference unfortunately

Comment: Have a look at how https://github.com/helpfulrobot/weboftalent-silverstripe-shortcode-youtube/blob/master/code/YouTubeShortCodeHandler.php is doing their template. try `$template = new SSViewer( 'FaqListing' );` `$customise['FaqListings'] = $drawerContentArray ;`  `return $template->process( new ArrayData( $customise) );`

Comment: then `<% loop $FaqListings %>` ...  `<% end_loop %>`